# Trying to gain knowledge of product tag behaviour

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to solve something.

I want the product tags to be the same as in the metadata from where they came from. Currently the product tags appear in alphabetical order on frontend (product pages) and in the database. I have product tags imported to db by a script which fetches the tags from metadata of images. The tags are inputted manually into metadata of images by users and they usually enter the most relevant words first, where as alphabetical order is basically random when it comes to order of importance.

Below is an example showing all the columns for the product tags table in database, which also shows the first few tags of a product. As you can see the tags are in alphabetical order, however the order of the tags in the metadata of the image are as follows; paper; old; vintage; oldish; age; ...

Can anyone let me know if the table is not structured correctly for the result I want? The person I'm working with said there is no primary key and that is what is responsible for the alphabetical order in the table, however I have a feeling there is something in the code I use to import the metadata to the table and this orders the tags alphabetically.

I don't know whether I should be looking for the relevant code in the script or if I need to change something in the database for the products tags to appear in the order they were originally given.

Thank you in advance for offering any insights to this.

[Tags in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nz7Ek.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding a timestamp column to product_tags in database.